# converting string with offset to timestamp in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timestamp, offset

how do I convert

```
'25/02/2014 10:49:13 -8'(datatype is VARCHAR)
```

to

```
'2014-02-25 13:50:13.000000'(datatype is TIMESTAMP)
```

in postgreSQL

I believe the timestamp is EST timezone.

Comment: Was a solution found for this? I am also unable to parse the offset for my strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try the method

> to_timestamp

Example:

```
to_timestamp('01 Jan 2007 09:09:09', 'DD Mon YYYY HH:MI:SS')
```

Hope This helps

Comment: Nope it does not, I have tried to_timestamp but the offset causes an imbalance. I want the offset which accounts for timezone to converted to the EST timezone as my other columns are of that format.